# Custom zip folder dont give option for save or open in browser

Tags: downloadable, zipcode

I have created a zip file programmatically. Zip is created on destination folder with specific files. But after creating that zip file why I am not getting an option to download (save) or open that zip file in browser ?

Please look in my code.

```
function cretezipAction()
{
   if(extension_loaded('zip'))
  {
      $destinationDir = Mage::getBaseDir('var').DS.'productzip'. DS . 'tempZipDir';
      if(!is_dir($destinationDir))
      {
         @mkdir($destinationDir);
      }
     $zip = new ZipArchive();
     $zipFileName = 'productsheets';
     $destinationDir = $destinationDir . DS . $zipFileName . '.zip';

     if(!$zip->open($destinationDir, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE))
     {
        return false;
     }
     $source = Mage::getBaseDir('var').DS.'productfile'.DS.'pdf';
      $someFilePathArray = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach($someFilePathArray as $filePath)
        {  
            $localname = substr($filePath,strrpos($filePath,'/') + 1); 
            $zip->addFile($filePath, $localname);
        }
        $zip->close();
        $downloadContent = file_get_contents($destinationDir); 


        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($zipFileName.'.zip', $downloadContent);
}
```

--------------- Update ---------------------

```
//$downloadContent = file_get_contents($destinationDir); 
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($zipFileName.'.zip', array( 'value' => $destinationDir, 'type' => 'filename' ));
```

Even after writing code "prepareDownloadResponse", I am not getting option for save or open zip file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistyping in your code, you have got the zip contents into `$downloadContent = file_get_contents($destinationDir);` but you try to send `$content` as a response `$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);` also I am not sure if `$fileName` is defined somewhere.

---update---

Please modify the last line like this:
`$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($zipFileName.'.zip', array('value' => $destinationDir, 'type' => 'filename'));`

Comment: Yes I have define $filename. But what to do next ? Can you please help me in this issue ?

Comment: @Aliana try this `$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $downloadContent);`

Comment: Same result. :( .  zip file saved on destination folder but not give option for download.

Comment: I have found wrong spelling of "prepareDownloadResponse" and I corrected that but now result is zip is created but they ask for download a pdf file which I was added in zip file. instead ask for download zip file.

Comment: @Aliana Please ensure you pass `$zipFileName.'.zip'` into _prepareDownloadResponse

Comment: I have updated my reply. Please check.

Comment: Now it is giving option to download zip file.But if I download that file and try to open that then windows is giving an error "Windows Cannot open the folder.The compressed folder <<path of pc>> is invalid. "   If i manually download file from destination directory and open the it is working fine.

Comment: I am passing "mycustomzip.zip" as a $filename.

Comment: I checked manually downloaded zip file and zip file from asking an option to download. Both zip file has same size.But when I tried to extract zip error comes with "Zipped folder is empty"

Comment: Do you have any suggetion or solution on this issue ?

Comment: Please confirm the file generated in `var/productzip/tempZipDir/productsheets.zip` and the downloaded via browser both have the same size in bytes. And the last one cannot be opened by windows? If so I have no sggestions more. I was trying to help you to check zip-file creation and to make it downloadable via browser as a response. Let me have a look at real current piece of code. You can modify your question with the latest version.

Comment: Please check my updated code.I am just doing as you said. And as you said in last reply . I checked both zip file's size.They are same. :(

Comment: @Aliana try this one `$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($zipFileName.'.zip', array(
    'value' => $destinationDir,
    'type' => 'filename'
));`
and you are able to leave file contents reading for Magento, comment out the line above with `file_get_contents`

Comment: Please check my update . Are you saying to do like that ? If yes then also it is not working.